# IBM Worklight 6.0 - URL shortening

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have build a simple web app using Worklight.

My apps Preview URL is : 
//local.loc:9080/Mobile/apps/services/preview/MobileAPP/common/0/default/MobileAPP.html

Shortend URL (with bit.ly credentials) is: http://bit.ly/153qbvr 
Here the domain is completely different (bit.ly).

But actually I am looking for URL like : http://local.loc:9080/Mobile/MobileAPP.html.

Are there any ways to get a URL for public access like: 
//:/application-name/launch_App_.html

if not, let me know ways to reduce the URL - if any.

Comment: if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 2):

The first URL you've mentioned is internal. It is meant for preview (development time mostly). Why would you be interested in shortening it? What is the value of doing so for you?

Also note that the shortened URL provided by bit.ly when using this service via Worklight - IS NOT the same URL as the first one (preview), it is meant for the Mobile Web environment, meaning for users who use their mobile browser app to access your app.

In short (no pun intended...), no, there is no way to do what you are asking for via Worklight - you cannot tweak the URL.
Let me re-iterate, the **preview** URL (the one mentioned in your question and that you want to shorten) is for the **administrator** or **developer**. It is NOT MEANT TO BE PUBLICALLY USED in any capacity, shape, form.

If you want to provide a web-public link to your app, add the `Desktop Browser` environment to your application. This environment is meant to access the app from a regular Desktop (PC/Mac) browser app. Note that even in this case, you cannot shorten the URL via a tweak in Worklight.

---

What you can do, is install some custom shortening service of your own in your company's servers and create your own custom URL that will look the way you want it to.